# what if I lost the keystore which generate the CSR

Tags: ssl, tomcat

Sorry I am a beginner about ssl cert.

according to

```
http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/ssl-howto.html#Create_a_local_Certificate_Signing_Request_(CSR)
```

it will gen a keystore and CSR.

we generate the CSR and send to Certificate Authority.

What if I lost the keystore ? should I regen the CSR again to reapply the ssl cert?

Refer to 
https://search.thawte.com/support/ssl-digital-certificates/index?page=content&id=SO832
It will generate a new keystore file.

is it the file store the private key? which stated in https://search.thawte.com/support/ssl-digital-certificates/index?page=content&id=SO750
, which say

```
1. Private Key file loss.

2. Private Key pass phrase loss.

3. Private Key file has been compromised due to the server being hacked.   
...... 
......
```

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, if you've lost the keystore then you've lost the private key.

The certificate generated from that CSR is now unusable to you, but the certificate authority should happily re-issue a new certificate if you generate a new CSR from a new private key.